# Is there a developer edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2017 for Linux?

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, license, sql-server-2017

I have SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition installed on Ubuntu, whis is free for development purposes:

> SQL Server 2016 SP1 Developer is a fully featured free edition licensed for use as a development and test database in a non-production environment.

I wanted to install SQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu as well. For Windows, on the SQL Server download page, there are three options - a trial evaluation, SQL Express (free but limited), and SQL Developer (free for non-production environments).

However, for Linux, there's just links for installing on Red Hat, Ubuntu, or SUSE.

When installed on Ubuntu, SQL Server 2017 (v.Next) says:

```
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password: 
Configuring SQL Server...

This is an evaluation version.  There are [174] days left in the evaluation period.
```

Is there a SQL Server 2017 Developers Edition for Linux? If so, where so I go to access it?

Note: This isn't a question about licensing, *per se*; it's about whether a 2017 version of the product I'm alreasdy using is available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing issues are off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple edition but you can only [buy the Standard Edition online,](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/buy/cart). The current price is $3,189.

> SQL Server 2017 Standard edition is available to buy online. Easily upgrade to Enterprise edition for comprehensive high-end datacenter capabilities.

The other edition require you to contact a ["Solutions Partner"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/solution-providers/search)

The developer edition remains free.

Answer (score 13):

**2017, May:**

SQL Server 2017 hasn't been released yet (only previews) so no licensing or pricing is available yet (the name `v.Next` should have been a clue!).

**2017, Dec:**

[SQL Server 2017 for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes) was released in October and the Developer Edition is free for development purposes, as in previous versions.

Comment: `v.Next` should have been a clue!